# Where do I wire up serilog-aspnetcore's UseSerilogRequestLogging extension method in a .NET Core 6 Worker Service?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, serilog, asp.net-core-6.0, serilog-aspnetcore

I'm trying to integrate Serilog and Seq into Visual Studio's .NET 6 Worker Service template, but I can't figure out where to wire up serilog-aspnetcore's UseSerilogRequestLogging extension method.

The template provides this implementation in Program.cs (to which I've added .UseSerilog and .UseWindowsService)

```
IHostBuilder hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => lc
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration))
    .UseWindowsService(options => { options.ServiceName = "My Service"; })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    });

IHost host = hostBuilder.Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

My packages

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Http" Version="6.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Expressions" Version="3.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Seq" Version="5.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Twilio.AspNet.Core" Version="6.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

I can't figure out where to wire up serilog-aspnetcore's UseSerilogRequestLogging extension method.

- Where is my application's IApplicationBuilder? (does it have one?)
- Or is there some other way I need to plug Serilog into the request pipeline?

```
public static IApplicationBuilder UseSerilogRequestLogging(
            this IApplicationBuilder app,
            string messageTemplate)
```

see [SerilogApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/blob/f56c26cb08497394e56d932df0bd8bdc84f49dd4/src/Serilog.AspNetCore/SerilogApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs)

Comment: `UseSerilogRequestLogging` is for integration with ASP.NET Core, based on provided code it looks like you have just some hosted job which does not handle http requests, so there is nothing to log.

Comment: The hosted job, named “Worker” in  this example (from the VS template) contains the requests. Worker derives from Microsoft’s BackgroundService class which implements IHostedService

Comment: I hate to ask this but are you sure "Worker" contains the code to handle the http requests. if it is possible to show us. because as far as I know you need to configure the request pipeline in the program.cs to be able to handle http request which I don't see in your code.

Comment: @nmarler please explain term "contain the requests". Again, unless it spins up ASP. NET Core instance which handles INCOMING requests `UseSerilogRequestLogging` should be pointless.